# Why is the length property of an array counting the number of chars in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I create an array and store strings in it but when i use the .length property with just one element in the array it counts the length of the string. With more than one element it counts the elements as usual.

```
private organizationArray: Array<string>;

const claims = jwtDecode<any>(token);
    this.claims = {
        email: claims['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/***/**/***/claims/emailaddress'],
        id: claims['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/***/**/*****/claims/sid'],
        name: claims['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/***/**/****/claims/name'],
        expires: new Date(claims['exp'] * 1000),
    };
this.organizationArray = claims['http://schemas.*****.**/**/****/**/*******/claims/organization'];
console.log( this.organizationArray.length)
```

Here i have 3 elements in the array:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/services/jwt.service.js:55:20: 3
```

Here i have 1 elements in the array with 84 chars:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/services/jwt.service.js:55:20: 84
```

claims returns

```
{"Id":"********-0000-0000-0000-********","Name":"NAME","AccessibleAreas":**},{"Id":"******-****-*****-****-******","Name":"Demo Inc.","AccessibleAreas":*}
```

Comment: What is in `claims`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not a part of a bigger program we need to bang into shape to verify. Also, this is not [tag:javascript], why is it tagged so?

Comment: `claims` probably returns one element instead of an array. You can do `this.organizationArray = this.organizationArray instanceof Array ? this.organizationArray : [this.organizationArray]`

Comment: but why does the .length property return 2 when I have two or more?

Comment: added the return of the claims in the post.

Comment: I mean `claims['http://schemas.*****.**/**/****/**/*******/claims/organization']`

Comment: it outputs 2 or 3 or 4 when there are 2 or 3 or 4 elements in the array but when i only have one element is outputs around 84 depending on the length of the string.

Comment: Are you certain that the result you get from the server doesn't return a single JSON object rather than a JSON array if only 1 object needs to be returned? Print the result you get from the server and check if an array or a single object is being returned when only 1 object needs to be returned.

Comment: @JohannesKraft Then in that case, `organizationArray` is not an array. If you need it to be an array like @ritaj suggested then you should do `this.organizationArray = this.organizationArray instanceof Array ? this.organizationArray : [this.organizationArray]`

Comment: When one is returned this is the output:         
`{"Id":"*****-0000-****-0000-*****","Name":"*****","AccessibleAreas":**}` that would indicate that its not an array?

Comment: Yes, it's just an object

Comment: @JohannesKraft Please try both requests with a tool like postman and see if the result has `[]` around the object(s)

Comment: Thanks both of you for helping me @nickzoum and @ritaj! I actually learned some new stuff here today! Loving the community feeling!